# Socket connection successful in emulator but showing error in mobile

Tags: android, c++, sockets, tcp

I am creating 2 sockets. Client is an android app and server code is written in c++.

To create socket:
in app:

```
socket = new Socket("192.168.1.1", 5026);
socket1 = new Socket("192.168.1.1", 5050);
```

in server side:

```
int sock::create_sock(int port_no, bool blocking)
{
    int sockfd, newsockfd;
    int portno = port_no;
    socklen_t clilen;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int n;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR opening socket");

    int enable = 1;

    if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &enable, sizeof(int)) < 0)
        error("setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR) failed");

    bzero((char *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        error("ERROR on binding");

    listen(sockfd, 5);
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    if (newsockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR on accept");

    if (blocking == false)
    {
        fcntl(newsockfd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);  // Change the socket into non-blocking state
        cout << "Creating non-blocking socket " << endl;
    }

    printf("server: got connection from %s port %d\n", inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(cli_addr.sin_port));

    close(sockfd);
    return newsockfd;
}
```

There is a connect button in the app. When the button is clicked, socket the java code to create socket runs.

Now the problem is the app runs fine in emulator. Both the sockets are getting connected no matter how many times I press connect. But when I run it in mobile, it connects only once. On subsequent clicking of the connect button, only the first socket is created and the second one stops before accepting function in server.

Comment: Does `new Socket` throw any exception when it does not connect?

Comment: Are you looking at `errno` when the calls fail?

Comment: The socket in java is throwing an exception. when i convert the exception to string and print it in a textview nothing gets displayed

Comment: @Eljay I am sure the error is from java side. Error is observed for socket1 = new Socket("192.168.1.1", 5050); I have not checked errno.